# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, selenium, pythonanywhere, undetected-chromedriver

I have deployed my script which is a scraper using undetected chrome ([this library](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)). Can some please let me know what is the problem.. We have updated selenium but still this problem shows at pythonanywhere console...

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agents}")

chrome_path = which("./chromedriver")
drive = uc.Chrome()
drive.maximize_window()

with drive:
    drive.get(Url)
drive.implicitly_wait(5)
```

It is a sample of code. We have enclosed in function and pass Urls (multiple) to it..  Need help regarding this issue.. As It works locally fine..

Comment: Try again with passing your chromedriver path to the `Chrome` constructor `uc.Chrome(chrome_path)`

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest Undetected chromedriver. I had a similar issue and was resolved by upgrading to v3.4.5 and excluding the ".v2" from the import "import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc"